# code optimisation in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working with dictionaries in python.

```
s = {'k1':['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg']}
```

I have created code as :

```
d = {}
for values in enumerate(s.values()[0]):
    if values[0]<2:
        d[values[1]] = 'True'
    else:
        d[values[1]] = 'False'
```

Can I convert this into one liner code using list comprehension or lambda?

I need answer as :

```
{'aa': 'True', 'bb': 'True', 'cc': 'False', 'dd': 'False', 'ee': 'False', 'ff': 'False', 'gg': 'False'}
```

updated - sry code typing mistake

Comment: Are you sure that this code is doing what you want it to do?  When I run it all I get is `>>> d {'ans': 'False'}`

Comment: code typing mistake sry. its updated

Comment: This will only store the value for the last element of `s.values()[0]`. Nobody else has pointed it out that clearly. You're always writing to the `ans` key of `d`. Should this key be a list? You could

Comment: What you've got now is just as incomprehensible in intent. *What is your* real *case?*

Comment: yes this is required. I want to attached values as I posted.

Comment: Ah, now we're getting somewhere... though I'm still not quite sure where...

Comment: sorry for mistakes. m newbie in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In response to:

```
d = {}
for values in enumerate(s.values()[0]):
    if values[0]<2:
        d['ans'] = 'True'
    else:
        d['ans'] = 'False'
```

the one liner is:

```
d = {'ans': str(len(s.values()[0]) < 2)}
```

What you are doing is nonsensical. Essentially the code you posted will always set `d['ans']` to `'True'` when `s.values()[0]` has a length less than `2` (else `'False'`). This is because the first element in the 2-tuple yielded by `enumerate` is the index (which you are comparing with `<2`). For all cases where the length of list is greater than 2, the `else` clause will keep setting it to `'False'`. You dont even need a loop for this.

**Update:**
For your new version:

```
d = dict( [(val, str(index < 2)) for (index, val) in enumerate(s.values()[0])] )
```

or

```
d = dict( [(i , "True") for i in li[:2]] + [(i, "False") for i in li[2:]] )
```

**update 2:** or if you want to update an existing dictionary:

```
d.update( (( (val, str(index < 2)) for (index, val) in enumerate(s.values()[0]) )) )
```

Comment: @preet : ur first updated version is good but that will create the new dict. i just wanted to update existing dictionary. for example, right now d = {} but what if d = {'zz':'22'}, then it should just update this dictionary and not creating new

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a really weird code.

Let's try rewriting it a little:

```
d={}
for values in s['k1']:
    d['ans'] = str(values[0] < 2)
```

What I don't get it is: do you understand that the value of d['ans'] will be the value of the last comparison?

And, to be honest, I really don't know exactly what the meaning of this. Could you clarify a little more?

Answer (score 1):

For starters, use tuple unpacking to make it slightly more palatable.

```
d = {}
for index, value in enumerate(s.itervalues()[0]):
    if index < 2:
        d[value] = 'True'
    else:
        d[value] = 'False'
```

Then cut down the inside of the loop:

```
d = {}
for index, value in enumerate(s.itervalues()[0]):
    d[value] = str(index < 2)
```

This can then be done as a dictionary comprehension:

```
d = {value: str(index < 2) for index, value in enumerate(s.itervalues()[0])}
```

Or, put in a different and perhaps nicer way,

```
thelist = s.itervalues()[0]
d = {value: 'True' for value in thelist[:2]}
d.update((value, 'False') for value in thelist[2:])
```

The intent of this code is, however, sadly incomprehensible.

The value of this is highly dubious as the ordering of dicts is not absolute. It ends up effectively being based upon a random element of the dictionary, across Python implementations and orders of construction of the dictionary.